# JQuery events wont work on dynamic content

Tags: jquery

I want to add a new line each time the enter key is pressed.  But delegation is not setup properly...  Can someone make the simple change to this code?
Thanks.`

Comment: where is the code?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/want5zv9/

Comment: Sorry... I forgot how difficult stackoverflow is to use...

Comment: `$(".myInput").on('keypress', ...` -> `$(document).on("keypress", ".myInput", ...`

Comment: For future reference, you can [edit] the question to add your code.  Please do read the [tour] and [ask] pages.  In this case, the linked question/answer should provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

dynamic content will not bind event
you can try this:

```
$('tbody').on('keypress', '.myInput', function(){
});
```

Comment: Both solutions worked!  Thank you both!